# If one independence case holds, why do the others hold too?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

**To use this question as an example:** In a class there are four freshman boys, six freshman girls, and six sophomore boys. How many sophomore girls must be present if sex and class are to be
independent when a student is selected at random?

Let $B = \rm boy$, $G = \rm girl$, $F = \rm freshman$, $S = \rm sophomore$, $x = \rm sophomore girls$.
There are four cases:

1. $P(FB) = P(F)P(B)$
2. $P(FG) = P(F)P(G)$
3. $P(SB) = P(S)P(B)$
4. $P(SG) = P(S)P(G)$

These cases assume independence.
Now if we solve for case 3 lets say, then x = 9.

The calculations are clear to me, but I don't understand why solving case 3 means that the other cases also hold when x = 9, it's not intuitive to me.

I tried showing myself that all other cases are independent as well, because we can use substitution to get 
$P(SB) = P(S)P(B)$ 
$P(SB) = (P(SG)/P(G))*P(B)$ 
Which shows that case 4 is independent. The thing I don't understand here is that, this is assuming that case 4 is indeed independent. Why is this possible?

**Question:** So what I'm trying to ask is, Why is it that if one case holds, the others hold too? Is there an intuitive way to think about such problems? Because I can't picture it in my mind, I can just do the calculation here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific example you have complementary events so that $G =$ girl and $G^{c}= $ boy as well as $F=$ freshman and $F^{c} =$ sophomore. Then your question just comes down to showing that if two events $A$ and $B$ are independent then so are $A$ and $B^c$, $A^c$ and $B$, and $A^c$ and $B^c$.

Such a fact is well known. I would advise you to show it yourself but if you need guidance then consult [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962698/prove-that-if-events-a-and-b-are-independent-then-the-complement-events-of-a-an?noredirect=1&lq=1) or/and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584114/complement-and-independence?noredirect=1)